# How to create empty 4x4 table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a little problem to create table with jQuery. Here is what I have get done so far.

jQuery:

```
function createPuzzleTable () {
  // Create table with id
  $pt = $('<table>').attr('id','puzzleTable');

  // For-loop to create rows
  for (var y=0; y<4; y++) {
    var $row = $pt.append($('<tr>'));
    // For-loop to create cells, text-method is only for test numbering cells
    for (var x=0; x<4; x++) {
      $row.children().append($('<td>').text(y*4+x+1));
    }
  }
  // Alert to show structure of table
  alert ($pt.prop('outerHTML'));

  // Fetch gameArea by id and add table.
  $('#gameArea').append($pt);
}
```

Alert (cleared up):

```
<table id="puzzleTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
    <tr></tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td>
    <tr></tr><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td>
    <tr></tr><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How to set <td>-elements inside <tr>-elements?

---

Solution (Thanks to Paolo Bergantino):

```
for (var y=0; y<4; y++) {
  var $row = $('<tr>');
  $pt.append($row);
  for (var x=0; x<4; x++) {
    $row.append($('<td>').text(y*4+x+1));
  }
}
```

Comment: `alert` should be deprecated. :|

Comment: `$row.children().append(...)` should be `$row.append(...)` just like you do for the rows.

Comment: @Dream Easter: `alert` is only for testing.
@Felix Kling: If I remove `children()` element then structure goes like <table...><tr></tr><tr>...</tr><td></td><td>...</td></table> so it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, because `$row` actually refers to the table, not the row. Change the line to `var $row = $('<tr>').appendTo($pt);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
var $row = $('<tr/>');
for(..) {
   $row.append($('<td/>')...);
}
$pt.append($row);
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me to understand better logic of jQuery. My code puts <td>-element in table than row.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a better way of doing this:

```
function createPuzzleTable () {
    // Create table with id
    var $pt = '<table id="puzzletable">';

    // For-loop to create rows
    for (var y=0; y<4; y++) {
         // For-loop to create cells, text-method is only for test numbering cells

        $pt += '<tr>';

        for (var x=0; x<4; x++) {
            $pt += '<td>';
            //add content to TD here
            $pt += '</td>';
        }

        $pt += '</tr>';
    }

    $pt += '</table>';
    $('#gameArea').append($pt);
}
```

Using this method means you only manipulate the DOM once, after you have already set up the table's HTML as a string.